# Convert Timestamp to a specific format using SQL BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to convert this timestamp 23.05.2022 08:57:15 UTC to 2022-05-23 08:57:15 UTC

Working with timestamp is my weakness, so I need help on this.

Thank you

Comment: Checkout the [Datetime Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions) of BigQuery.

Comment: Already check that and I can't seem to find the right function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using format strings, you can parse and format timestamp data. Consider below query

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%F %T %Z', PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d.%m.%Y %T %Z', '23.05.2022 08:57:15 UTC'));

-- output : 2022-05-23 08:57:15 UTC
```